# Lookup if Dictionary key contains items in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lookup

If I have the following dictionary and list, is there a way that I can looking is the items in the list are contained within the keys of the dictionary?

I tried inverting the dictionary and looking up the values, but keys cant have the same values so it messes up the schema.

```
('dict', {'2D 4D': 0, '1B 2C': 0})
('list', ['2B', '2D', '3D', '4D', '4A'])
```

so when you ask something similar to

```
if key in dict:  //if '2D' is in dict
dict[key]+=1     //{'2D 4D': 1}
```

Comment: create additional dictionary from original dic like `{'2D': ['2D 4D'], '4D': ['2D 4D'], '1B': ['1B 2C'], '2C': ['1B 2C']}` and use it to lookup keys in original dic by searched term.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare each dict key entry to all in your list. For clean code purposes, don't use `dict`/`list` as var names:

```
mdict = {'2D 4D': 0, '1B 2C': 0}
mlist = ['2B', '2D', '3D', '4D', '4A']
for k in mdict.keys():
    for e in mlist:
        if e in k:
            mdict[k] += 1
# mdict:
{'1B 2C': 0, '2D 4D': 2}
```

If you have a huge list of words or dictionary entries, this will be slow. I suggest implementing a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of your list entries and iterate with that, which will reduce the complexity from O(M*N) to O(N+M).

Comment: is there a way to count the number of items in the key? i.e. `len(2D 4D) = 2`?

Comment: print ([(key,len(key.split(' '))) for key in mdict.keys()]) @WilliamMerritt

Comment: To add to @ncica, if your list contains *a lot of* duplicates, you can do `collections.Counter(mlist)` first and then iterate over the keys, will save tonnes of time.

Answer (score 0):

If keys of the dict are assumed to be in the way of having a space in the middle, you can use this also.

```
a = {'2D 4D': 0, '1B 2C': 0}
b = ['2B', '2D', '3D', '4D', '4A']
for i in a.keys():
    a[i]=len(set(i.split()).intersection(b))
```

OUTPUT:

```
 {'2D 4D': 2, '1B 2C': 0}
```